# Why is the output 1? Can someone explain me step by step about what is happening in the second line here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, brackets

```
const a=[1,2,3,4,5];
const [n]=a;
console.log(n);
```

I need to know how does something inside square brackets after const means, and why it stored only 1 and not the entire array.

Comment: it's destructuring assignment

Comment: You create a variable `n` which gets the first value of the array `a` assigned to. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is ES6 Destructuring Assignment.

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5];
const [n] = a;
const [m, o] = a;
const [p, q, r] = a;
const [...s] = a;
const [t, u] = a;
console.log(n); // 1
console.log(m, o); // 1 2
console.log(p, q, r); // 1 2 3
console.log(...s); // 1 2 3 4 5
console.log(u); // 2
```